# How to use type-level literal numbers in singletons?

Tags: haskell

I want to use singletons to represent ports at the type level, with type literals for the port numbers. Something like this:

```
data Port = Port Integer

foo :: Sing ('Port 80)
foo = sing

bar :: Port
bar = fromSing foo
```

Short form of question is, how to implement this, or something resembling it?

I tried using singletons-2.0.1 with ghc-7.10.3

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, GADTs, KindSignatures, DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, FlexibleContexts, RankNTypes, UndecidableInstances, FlexibleInstances,  InstanceSigs, DefaultSignatures, DataKinds, PolyKinds #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TH
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import GHC.TypeLits

$(singletons [d|
   data Port = Port Nat
  |])

foo.hs:8:3:
     Couldn't match type ‘Integer’ with ‘Nat’
     Expected type: DemoteRep 'KProxy
       Actual type: Nat
     In the first argument of ‘toSing’, namely ‘b_a4Vk’
     In the expression: toSing b_a4Vk :: SomeSing (KProxy :: KProxy Nat)
```

So, sounds like it wants data Port = Port Integer, but that also fails to build too:

```
foo.hs:8:3:
    ‘Port’ of kind ‘*’ is not promotable
    In the kind ‘Port -> *’
    In the type ‘(Sing :: Port -> *)’
    In the type declaration for ‘SPort’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I managed to get further than this, although not all the way, by not using the singletons library, but implementing a simplified version myself.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeOperators, TypeFamilies, GADTs, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Proxy (KProxy(..), Proxy(..))

data Port = Port Nat

data family Sing (x :: k)

class SingI t where
    sing :: Sing t

class (kparam ~ 'KProxy) => SingKind (kparam :: KProxy k) where
    type DemoteRep kparam :: *
    fromSing :: Sing (a :: k) -> DemoteRep kparam

type SNat (x :: Nat) = Sing x
data instance Sing (n :: Nat) = KnownNat n => SNat
instance KnownNat n => SingI n where sing = SNat
instance SingKind ('KProxy :: KProxy Nat) where
    type DemoteRep ('KProxy :: KProxy Nat) = Integer
    fromSing (SNat :: Sing n) = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n)

data instance Sing (x :: Port) where
        SPort :: Sing n -> Sing ('Port n)
instance KnownNat n => SingI ('Port (n :: Nat)) where sing = SPort sing
```

So far, so good, now this works:

```
foo :: Sing ('Port 80)
foo = sing
```

But I'm stuck implementing fromSing for Port.

```
instance SingKind ('KProxy :: KProxy Port) where
        type DemoteRep ('KProxy :: KProxy Port) = Port
        fromSing (SPort n) = Port (fromSing n)
```

This fails with the same type error as shown for the first use of the singletons library above. And now, it's clear why: the SingKind instance for Nat produces an Integer, not a Nat. It seems it has to, because natVal produces an Integer.

So, I'm stuck!

Comment: The core problem is that the type `Port` is uninhabited, because the type `Nat` is uninhabited. singletons will generate `type DemoteRep ('KProxy :: KProxy Port) = Port` so any implementation of `{to/from}Sing` will necessarily be wrong. The simplest solution is to define `data Port a = Port a` and make singletons for that type, which allows you to have `DemoteRep ('Port (n :: Nat)) ~ Port Integer`. This will properly give you e.g. `toSing (Port (10 :: Integer)) :: SomeSing ('KProxy :: KProxy (Port Nat))`

Answer (score 5):

The main *singletons* idiom right now is to parameterize `Port`:

```
data Port nat = Port nat
```

(wrapped in the corresponding singletons quasiquoter, of course)

And, your normal data-level `Port` would be:

```
type Port' = Port Integer
```

and your type-level `Port` would be:

```
Port Nat
```

(which isn't yet allowed as a kind synonym, but should be allowed in GHC 8.0)

So, you have the *type* `Port Integer` inhabited by the values `Port 1`, `Port 2`, etc., and the *kind* `Port Nat` inhabited by the types `Port 1`, `Port 2`, etc.

The reason why this works out with the *singletons* library is because `Integer` is the singleton for `Nat`, so the singleton for `Port Nat` is `Port Integer`, automatically, for free.  So everything works out like you'd expect when you use `SingI`, `Sing`, `toSomeSing`, etc. -- reflecting a `Port Nat`-kinded type will give you a `Port Integer`-type value, and reifying a `Port Integer`-type value will give you a `Port Nat`-kinded type.

Answer (score 3):

Would something much simpler, without singletons, work for you?

```
{-# language DataKinds, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Proxy
import GHC.TypeLits

data Port = Port{ portNumber :: Integer }
data PortT = PortT Nat

webPort :: Proxy ('PortT 80)
webPort = Proxy

reify :: forall n. (KnownNat n) => Proxy ('PortT n) -> Port
reify _ = Port (natVal (Proxy :: Proxy n))
```

this gives you

```
*Main> portNumber $ reify webPort
80
```